# Which should I use: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration OR Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-webjobs, asp.net-core-1.0

I have an ASP.NET Core app and I'm currently using IConfiguration interface from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.

Looks like IConfiguration interface is also available through Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.

Which one am I supposed to use? My ASP.NET Core app is working fine but when I tried to share some class libraries with an Azure WebJobs app, I got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel` was [renamed](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/25) to `Microsoft.Framework.Configuration` and [then](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/77) to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`. You might have some out of date package references in your WebJob?